# withCredentials: true is set but session variable is still missing in express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, express

I am building cross domain web application with React and express
They run at port 3000 and 3001 respectively
I am trying to send a post request to create and record to database  base on the user id that set in the req.session
My problem is that session variable become undefined after the set up of CORS()
I have search through similar post and try to follow their instruction and solution
none of them works for me so I decide to come up here

Here is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: apiEndPoint + 'create',
  data: data,
  xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
  success: results=>{
    //do something
  }
})
```

Here is my app.js setup for cors

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
var session = require('express-session');

...

var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    credentials: true
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'randomstringhere', 
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
app.use('/', notesRouter);

...

app.listen(3001);
```

value inside req.session

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
```

Comment: Why is the `url` field in your ajax request a relative one (`/create`)? If your backend is being served on a different port than your frontend, then you should specify the entire URL (`http://localhost:3001/create`) in your request.

Comment: It just a typo. I have modified some code before asking the question. Just to reduce the complexity. Thank for pointing out